# Python Requests Login to Login With Amazon to get Access Token for Amazon Advertising API

Tags: redirect, oauth-2.0, amazon-advertising-api

I am trying to use python requests to receive my access token for the Amazon Advertising API. The procedure is outlined here: https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/v2/guides/authorization Here is what I tried

```
CLIENT_ID = MyClientID
CLIENT_SECRET = MySecret
RETURN_URL = 'https://myreturn.com/my.php'

headers = {
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.61 Safari/537.36',
          }

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    r = s.get('https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id={}&scope=cpc_advertising:campaign_management&error=access_denied&response_type=code&redirect_uri={}'.format(CLIENT_ID,RETURN_URL),headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    data = {}
    form = soup.find('form', {'name': 'signIn'})
    for field in form.find_all('input'):
        try:
            data[field['name']] = field['value']
        except:
            pass
    data[u'email'] = MY_EMAIL
    data[u'password'] = MY_PASS
    b = s.post('https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id={}&scope=cpc_advertising:campaign_management&response_type=code&redirect_uri={}',data=data,allow_redirects=True,headers=headers)
```

i get an error_description=User+not+authenticated&error=access_denied error, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi Guguma, Did you got the solution to automate it. Do we have to sign-in everytime. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You DON'T NEED Username and Password in your Python Script to authenticate!
What you need is **CLIENT_ID, SCOPE** and **REDIRECT_URI** and three requests:

1. Get authorization code:

   `GET https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id={{CLIENT_ID}}&scope={{SCOPE}}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={{REDIRECT_URI}}`

This will open the 'Login with Amazon' Consent Page, where you (or your customer) log into your Amazon Seller Central account and grant access to the Console APP with API access rights.

2. Request tokens

   `POST https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token`

   with headers:

   `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

   with body data:

   ```
   grant_type:authorization_code
   code:{{AUTH_CODE}}    <----- returned from step 1
   client_id:{{CLIENT_ID}}
   client_secret:{{CLIENT_SECRET}}
   redirect_uri:{{REDIRECT_URI}}
   ```
3. Get/Refresh **access token** (every time it is outdated):

   `POST https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token`

   with headers:

   ```
   Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   charset:UTF-8
   ```

   with body data:

   ```
   grant_type:refresh_token
   refresh_token:{{REFRESH_TOKEN}}   <------ returned from step 2
   client_id:{{CLIENT_ID}}
   client_secret:{{CLIENT_SECRET}}
   ```

---

4. With the CLIENT_ID and (fresh) access token you can now request every service from the API. For excample listCampaigns:

   `GET https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v2/sp/campaigns`

   Headers:

   ```
   Content-Type:application/json
   Amazon-Advertising-API-ClientId:{{CLIENT_ID}}
   Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope:{{PROFILE_ID}}
   Authorization:Bearer {{ACCESS_TOKEN}}   <----- returned from step 3
   ```

Comment: Hi tector, I'm confused what does `profile_id` in `Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope:{{PROFILE_ID}}` mean above, could you pls tell me how can I get a profile_id?

Comment: You can get a list of your profile ids with  
`GET https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v2/profiles`  
You will see one profile id per marketplace.  
See: https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/reference/2/profiles

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I've tried with your suggestion, but I always get error like `{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","details":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized","requestId":"AAY9QFJ3NBEPJYBTK030"}` both in `https://advertising-api-test.amazon.com/v2/profiles` and `https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v2/profiles`

Comment: And I applied for  API access and sign up the [form](https://advertising.amazon.com/about-api) but I didn't receive the accept email from amazon.I'm very confusing about that.

Comment: Okay then, you need a confirmation mail from Amazon to have a Seller Account with API Access. Please ask Amazon for Support.

Comment: @tector, dopes it mean I need to get refresh tokens for each each region? So for exampl, my app have a dropdown where the customer selects what region she want to authorize our app

Comment: I guess so, yes. But don't confuse region with profile: If your app is only for european profiles, it is enough to get one refresh token for region EU.

Comment: jia jimmy- Make sure you are supplying the headers with your requests, otherwise you will get that UNAUTHORIZED error. Also, tector is correct- you don't need the username/password after the first time. Once you obtain the refresh token- for all future instances you can use this refresh token (does not expire) to obtain a new access token.