# Access multiple Amazon Seller accounts and gather their data from Amazon Advertising API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, login-with-amazon, amazon-advertising-api

I am developing a web app which will be pulling data from Amazon Advertising API. I need as a user to see data for all of the sellers that has approved/registered for using their profile's data.

Is this scenario possible? If not, is there anything similar to it? If yes, how do I implement it, is there some documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Amazon Advertising API v2 was released late 2018, so it's pretty new but has some missing information in the official documentation. But to get started please follow the official documentation guide:

https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/v2/guides/get_started

A lot of other sources are outdated, so I suggest to stick to this guide.

The logic to handle multiple Amazon Seller Accounts you have to handle yourself.
But every Seller Account has to go through the consent workflow to give your console app the rights to get access to the shop data via API. Therefore you need to implement a **'Login with Amazon'** button - That's the part that is not mentioned in the documentation. See https://login.amazon.com/

Comment: I am familiar to that guide and I have followed it successfully to the very end. 
The problem is the logic approach in the development to use all of the accounts in the app.
How do I do that? Is it the token that is received through LWA that I need to save in the DB and then access it every time I use the app as a user?

Comment: Yes, you receive ACCESS and REFRESH TOKEN from LWA. You need to store the refresh token, because it gives you long term access. The access token is only valid for 5 minutes or so. With the REFRESH TOKEN you can get anytime a new fresh ACCESS TOKEN. And with the ACCESS TOKEN you can request all the api services.

So you have to store REFRESH TOKEN for each seller account you want to manage. (plus maybe CLIENT ID and CLIENT SECRET if they differ, but that depends on your setup)

Comment: maybe this related topic can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56837581/850547